# Does the existence of a continuous function on a topological space imply that that space is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

It makes sense to me that this would be true but I am not sure.

My understanding of (at least one of the definitions of) a continuous function is that

- for every point $p$ in the functions, domain, there exsits a neighborhood $N$ around that point
- There is a neighborhood $f(N)$ in the function's image that corresponds to $N$
- As the width of $N$ shrinks to $0$, so does the width of $f(N)$

This seems to imply that the topological space the function is defined on is Hausdorff, since for any two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ in the space, we can always find a neighborhood around $p_1$ that does not include $p_2$ and vice versa. Otherwise, our function could not be continuous at $p_1$ or $p_2$.

If this is not true, are there any other conditions on the function or the space that could make this true?

Comment: All constant functions are continuous between any topologies, therefore given two topological spaces $X,Y$ the following are equivalent: 1) there is no continuous function $X\to Y$; 2) $X\ne\emptyset=Y$.

Comment: All constant functions on any topological space are continuous. By the way, do you intend for the codomain of your function to be the space of real numbers? If so, this should be stated.

Comment: What if you don't have "width" defined on your topological space?

Comment: This isn't quite a correct definition of "continuous function" in the setting of abstract topological spaces! Have you seen the formal definition of "topological space"? A sort of similar condition that does work is "for any two distinct points $x_1, x_2 \in X$, there is some Hausdorff space $Y$ (eg $\Bbb R$ or $[0, 1]$) and a map $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$." Another is "there is a continuous injection from $X$ to some Hausdorff space". (In fact both are necessary as well.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's some major misunderstandings here. First of all lets talk about continuity at a point. The proper definition is:

> A function $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is continuous at $x\in X$ if for any open neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$ in $Y$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$.
>
> Then we will say $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if it is continuous at every point.

The (global) continuity has a simpler description though:

> A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ for any open subset $U$ of $Y$.

Therefore it is quite easy to see that given two nonempty topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ every constant function $X\to Y$ is continuous. Sometimes there aren't other continuous functions (e.g. when $X$ is connected while $Y$ totally disconnected), but there always is at least as many as elements of $Y$.

In particular whether those spaces are Hausdorff or not is irrelevant.

Also topological spaces don't have a concept of width. Even though it is sometimes useful to think about them in terms of something more intuitive like metric spaces (where width can be defined) this particular intuition doesn't really fit here.

Btw this:

> This seems to imply that the topological space the function is defined on is Hausdorff, since for any two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ in the space, we can always find a neighborhood around $p_1$ that does not include $p_2$ and vice versa.

is not definition of being Hausdorff. Hausdorff means that every two distinct points have non-intersecting neighbourhoods. However what you described here is a weaker condition, known as [$T_1$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space). But that is not important anyway.